# How to add elements over video

Tags: video, editing, video-editing

I was watching this video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FCSBoOcGFFE

And I'm wondering what kind of software you would need in order to take the original and add in the over-layed objects (e.g. the guitar and keyboards held by the newcasters, the batman-like words as the guy is singing, etc).

Is there a non-professional package that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking at is just a simple green screen/Chroma key effect.

You can do this for free in [Windows Movie Maker](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dtFYD-2NRMc) on Windows and IMovie on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you expect a *non-professional* program to do this? "Non-professional" – at least for me – implies that it lacks features professionals use, which is just the case in the video here.

For example:

- Element composition, titles, layers
- Greenscreening / Bluescreening, [Chroma Keying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_screen)

[Adobe Premiere](http://www.adobe.com/products/premiere.html) and [After Effects](http://www.adobe.com/products/aftereffects.html) are the professional tools for achieving this. On OS X, you can also use [Final Cut Pro](http://www.apple.com/finalcutpro/top-features/).

For free? On Windows, you have Movie Maker, and on OS X, you have iMovie for video editing. Here's a video about [chroma keying in iMovie](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-ekc19csWM), and here's an article about [doing it in Windows Movie Maker](http://www.ehow.com/how_2240224_chroma-key-windows-movie-maker.html), but I haven't tried them for this task yet.